# Preventing sandbox from sending Workflow emails to "Additional Emails"

Tags: email, workflow, sandbox, notification

When you create a sandbox in Salesforce.com, the system is appending the sandbox name to every single email, except the "Additional Emails". In our company, since we need to notify some external entities about specific events occurring in our Salesforce.com instance, we don't want them to receive any email coming from the sandbox.

What can I do to prevent this? Is there a built-in feature?

Comment: You can turn off all emails in a Sandox. Look under Setup > Email Administration > Deliverablity. Changing the access level to System or No Access will prevent workflow emails from being sent at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Salesforce.com Help Docs

> Newly created sandboxes have the default email deliverability setting System email only.To configure email deliverability settings, in the sandbox organization, click **Your Name** | **Setup** | **Email Administration** | **Deliverability**. If editable, set the Access level in the Access to Send Email section. You may not be able to edit the Access level if salesforce.com has restricted your organization’s ability to change this setting.
>   No access>: Prevents all outbound email to and from users.
>   System email only: Allows only automatically generated emails, such as new user and password reset emails.
>   All email>: Allows all types of outbound email. Default for new, non-sandbox organizations.

**Sandbox Setup Tips and Considerations**

src: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Good to know. The sandbox was set as "All Email" by default, not sure why.

EDIT: I checked three sandbox (for three different org instance in Salesforce.com) and they are all set at "All Email" by default in the sandbox. I think this is seriously problematic to set that by default when generating a new sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Deliverability "System Email Only" option is a solution, in many cases.

Eg: I need to test a confirmation email, that loads internally a list of users. The solution would be to mask any email address different than the Admin User's email address.